# how to decode colnames pandas dataframe with python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I imported a data frame in python with pandas. 
But I have column names with strange encoding.

```
colnames = ['Price \xe2\x82\xac', 'x-rate \xe2\x82\xac/$']
```

Can you help me to decode these column names?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what the source encoding was? What did you import from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
colnames = [i.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8') for i in colnames]
```

Yields:

```
['Price €', 'x-rate €/$']
```

Per @piRSquared's comment, you can do this with `pandas` using:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode())
```

Comment: Bring it back to `pandas` with `df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode())`

Comment: Edited my answer, thank you for the reminder to tie it back to `pandas`.